# Emoji support for chrome on linux

Tags: fonts, web-fonts, linux

I am on a CentOS 7 machine, I want to take a PDF export of my website that has emojis in it using puppeteer (that internally used Chromium). But natively, very few emojis are supported on linux, and that too in black and white. So I found to options to get the emojis rendered:

- [Google Noto](https://www.google.com/get/noto/#emoji-zsye-color)
- [Emoji One](https://github.com/emojione/emojione/tree/master/extras/fonts)

Using Google Noto or Emoji One's Android fonts, on browser, it looks ok, but the PDF export shows up as emojis overlapped by weird characters: 
[image: Google Noto]

Using Emoji One's apple fonts, on browser as well as PDF export, the skin tones of faces appear to be separated besides the normal emoji inside a circle:
[image]

Can you please suggest a way to solve these rendering issues. Or suggest an alternative emoji font for linux.

Comment: How is OS font support a graphic design question? That's perhaps a better fit in [unix.se]

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/436260/emoji-support-for-chrome-on-linux
had already asked there...no reply

Comment: Well you just asked yesterday... Also please do not cross post.

Comment: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1):

Twitter Color Emoji SVGinOT Font for Unicode 10.0 and Emoji 5.0 is a nice repo to start with.

https://github.com/eosrei/twemoji-color-font

[image]

*Note: This requires Bitstream Vera is installed and will change your systems default serif, sans-serif and monospace fonts.*

Additionally you can try the Symbola font.

Just run `sudo apt-get install ttf-ancient-fonts` in Ubuntu 16.04 and other Ubuntu-based distributions to install it.

Comment: But SVGinOT is not supported in Chrome. I have already tried it, i get fallback fonts on chrome.

It says in the repo:
'Reiterating: Only FireFox supports the SVGinOT color emoji for now. Safari and Chrome will use the fallback black and white emoji.'

Comment: @mohsinulhaq https://github.com/eosrei/emojione-color-font/issues/57

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04+ you can simply install the package`fonts-noto-color-emoji` and restart Chrome! `:-)`